# If a series is not a power series, is the notion of radius of convergence still legit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series

This notion is defined over complex power series. But what about complex series not in a "power" form?
Is the convergence region always form a circle centered at origin in the complex plane?

Answer (score 1):

No, certainly not. For example,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (f(z))^k
$$
converges if and only if $|f(z)| < 1$ and that set is (in general) not a disc.

For a concrete example with an interesting domain of convergence, take
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sin^k z. $$